# Non-measurable sets on $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

I'm familiar with the "construction" of non-measurable sets on $\mathbb{R}$. But of interest to me is if there is a way to construct a countably additive probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{N}$ such that we can't extend $\mu$ to $2^{\mathbb{N}}$. Apparently there's no way to do it when $\mu$ is defined on all singletons, as for any set $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, we have
\begin{align*}
\mu(S) & = \sum_{k \in S} \mu( \{k \}) \\
& = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \chi_{S} \mu( \{k\} )
\end{align*}
Clearly we have that $\mu(\mathbb{N}) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \mu ( \{k\}) = 1$, so we know that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k = N + 1}^{\infty} \mu( \{ k \} ) = 0$. But then we use this to show that $\mu(S)$ is well-defined, as the sum converges. Let $\epsilon > 0$, and let $N$ be large enough that $\sum_{k = N + 1}^{\infty} \mu( \{k \}) < \epsilon$.
\begin{align*}
\left| \left( \sum_{k \in S} \mu( \{k\}) \right) - \left( \sum_{k = 1}^{N} \mu( \{ k \} ) \right) \right| & = \left| \sum_{k = N + 1}^{\infty} \chi_{S} \mu(\{k\}) \right| \\
& \leq \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \| \chi_{S} \mu(\{k\}) \| \\
& \leq \sum_{k = N + 1}^{\infty} \mu( \{k\} ) \\
& < \epsilon .
\end{align*}
So is there a way to define a measure on $\mathbb{N}$ that is finite, but cannot be extended to measure the singletons? Is it possible if we drop the assumption that $\mu$ be finite? Can we show instead that any countably additive measure will extend to all of $2^{\mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: A potential followup question: is it possible to define $\mu$ so that $\mu(m \Bbb N + n) = \frac 1m$ for $m,n \in \Bbb N$?

Comment: I think that's a no, because it would return null singletons. Assume just a second that $\mathbb{N}$ starts on $0$. Fix $k$, and let $E_{m} = (k \mod m) + m \mathbb{N}$. Then $ k \in E_{m}$, so $\mu (E_m) = \frac{1}{m} /geq \mu(\{k\})$, but $1/m \to 0$. Thus every singleton is null, so countable subadditivity would say $\mathbb{N}$ is null.

Comment: My suspicion is that this "measure" would extend to the density function, which I do not believe to be a measure.

Comment: @AJY : Actually in that case singletons have to be measurable since $$\mu(\{k\}) = \mu(\cap_n k + 2^n \mathbb N) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 1/2^n = 0.$$

Comment: But that would be a contradiction, as $\mu ( \mathbb{N} ) = \mu( 0 + 1\mathbb{N} ) = 1 = \mu ( \cup_{k = 1}^{\infty} \{k\} ) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \mu( \{k\} ) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} 0 = 0$

Comment: If a measure is null on the singletons, then it's null on a countable set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(\mathbb N, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a measure space. Consider for each $x \in \mathcal F$ the set 
$$
\mathcal F_x = \underset{x \in S}{\bigcap_{S \in \mathcal F}} S.
$$
We can take this intersection to be countable, since for each $y \in \mathcal F_x$, we can pick one $S_y \in \mathcal F$ with $x,y \in \mathcal F$ and and for each $z \in \mathbb N \backslash \mathcal F_x$, we pick one $S_z \in \mathcal F$ with $\mathcal F_x \subseteq S \not\ni z$. The intersection over all $S_y$ and $S_z$ is countable and equals $\mathcal F_x$, so $\mathcal F_x \in \mathcal F$.

For each $x,y \in \mathbb N$, either $\mathcal F_x = \mathcal F_y$ or $\mathcal F_x \cap \mathcal F_y = \varnothing$. For suppose $\mathcal F_x \neq \mathcal F_y$, so that there exists $S \in \mathcal F$ with $x \in \mathcal F$ and $y \notin \mathcal F$ (we can assume this without loss of generality, otherwise reverse the roles of $x$ and $y$). It follows that $\mathcal F_y \subseteq \mathbb N \backslash S$ by definition of $\mathcal F_y$ since $y \in \mathbb N \backslash S \in \mathcal F$, so $\mathcal F_x \cap \mathcal F_y = \varnothing$.

So the sets $\{ \mathcal F_x \, | \, x \in \mathbb N \}$ form a partition of $\mathbb N$. Write $\{\mathcal F_1,\cdots, \} = \{ \mathcal F_i \, | \, i \in I \}$ for the set of sets that partition $\mathbb N$ ($I$ could be finite or countably infinite), and let $\{x_1,\cdots,\}$ be a sequence (might be finite or infinite) of elements with the property that $x_i \in \mathcal F_i$. By assumption, for all $y \in \mathcal F_i$, $\mathcal F_y = \mathcal F_i$, so $\mu(\{y\})$ is defined if and only if $\{y\} = \mathcal F_i = \{x_i\}$.

Since you wish to assume $\mu$ finite, we have $0 \le \mu(\mathcal F_i) \le \mu(\mathbb N) < \infty$, so there are actually plenty of ways to extend $\mu$ to a measure to all of $\mathbb N$. Your options go like this. If you give $\mathcal F_i$ the measure subspace structure, you obtain a space $(\mathcal F_i, \{ \varnothing, \mathcal F_i \}, \mu)$ where $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$ and $\mu(\mathcal F_i)$ is what it was in $(\mathbb N, \mathcal F,\mu)$. So you extend $(\mathcal F_i, \{ \varnothing, \mathcal F_i \}, \mu)$ to $(\mathcal F_i, \mathcal P(\mathcal F_i), \mu_i)$ by assigning values $\mu(\{y\})$ to each $y \in \mathcal F_i$ such that $\mu_i(\{y\}) \ge 0$ for each $y$ and $\sum_{y \in \mathcal F_i} \mu_i(\{y\}) = \mu(\mathcal F_i)$. Then you let $(\mathbb N, \mathcal P(\mathbb N), \widetilde{\mu})$ be a measure space defined by 
$$
\widetilde{\mu}(A) \overset{def}= \sum_{i \in I} \mu_i(A \cap \mathcal F_i). 
$$
Note that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \widetilde{\mu}(\{n\})$ is then absolutely convergent since in positive series, we can re-arrange the terms in any order we want, so 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \widetilde{\mu}(\{n\}) = \sum_{i \in I} \widetilde{\mu}(\mathcal F_i) = \sum_{i \in I} \mu(\mathcal F_i) = \mu(\mathbb N) < \infty.
$$
This extension will always work, even in the non-finite case, but of course in the non-finite case the extension will also not be finite. Also, since you need to fix new values for originally non-measurable subsets, you have uniqueness if and only if $\mathcal F = \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, so essentially in any non-trivial case the extension is not unique.

Hope that helps,

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, then we're saying the $\sigma$-algebra being less than the power set induces a sort of "indistinguishability" property, like in topology, where $x \equiv y$ if every measurable set containing $x$ also contains $y$. Every equivalence class $[x]$ is measurable; if every equivalence class $[x]$ is singleton, then every singleton is measurable, and so we're done. If not, then we take each non-singleton equivalence, and assign a function $f_{[x]} : [x] \to [0, 1]$ s.t. $\sum_{y \in [x]} f_{[x]}(y) = \mu ([x])$. Let $\nu (\{x\}) = f_{[x]}(x)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Moreover, it seems there are continuum many extensions of an un-extended measure. Dose the construction of these functions require some sort of choice axioms?

Comment: @AJY : Except that $f_{\mathcal F_i} : \mathcal F_i \to [0,\mu(\mathcal F_i)]$ (using my notation, with yours it would be $f_{[x]} : [x] \to [0,\mu([x])]$), your first comment is right.

Comment: As for your second comment, if $\mathcal F_i$ is finite for each $i$, then you don't need choice at all : you simply define $\mathcal f_{[x]}(x) = \frac {\mu([x])}{|[x]|}$. However, this definition does not work if $[x]$ is infinite, and there you need to choose in some sense where the "weight" lies (there is no uniform density on $\mathbb N$).

Comment: But in this case you need to define at most countably many functions on countable sets (you can do it in your favorite way, say by picking $x \in \mathcal F_i$ and giving it all the weight, i.e. $\mu(\{x\}) = \mu([x])$ for instance), so the amount of choice required to do this is not arbitrary, just countable.

Comment: For the record, I am saying that I *can* do it with countable choice, but not that it's impossible without it. I'm not sure if the following approach requires choice, perhaps some logician could correct me on that : 

for each $i \in I$, let $x_i = \min_{x \in \mathcal F_i} x$. Then let $f_i : \mathcal F_i \to [0,\mu(\mathcal F_i)]$ be defined by $f_i(x_i) = \mu(\mathcal F_i)$ and $f_i(y) = 0$ otherwise.

I think it doesn't need choice since all I need to do is to prove that any non-empty subset of $\mathbb N$ has a minimal element, and this can be done by checking finitely many integers.

Comment: It seems that the well-order of $\mathbb{N}$ should make that trivial, but I was thinking about where every singleton had positive measure.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\sim$ be any equivalence relation on $\mathbb N$. Define a measure on $\mathbb N/\sim$. Then $\mathbb N$ inherits this measure, and the measurable sets are exactly unions of equivalence classes. In particular, if $\sim$ is not the equality relation, then there are non-measurable sets.

For example, we can define $x\sim y$ if $x,y$ have the same prime factors.

But what this really means is that your probability space has indistinguishable events.

As another answer proves, this is essentially the only sort of measure that can be of this kind.

Given such a measure, define: $x\sim y$ if every measurable set that contains $x$ contains $y.$

This is an equivalence relation since

1. If there is a measurable set $S$ containing $y$ but not $x$ then $\mathbb N\setminus S$ is a measurable set containing $x$ not containing $y$.
2. If $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$ then any set containing $x$ contains $y$ and hence contains $z$.
3. $x\sim x$ fairly obviously.

If $A_x$ is the equivalence class of $x$, then $A_x=\int_{y\not\sim x} A_{x,y}$ of measurable sets not containing the elements not equivalent to $x$, and this is a countable intersection.

Such measures can always be extended pretty trivially to $\mathcal P(S)$, by either picking a single element of each set as the "real" element, leaving all others with measure zero, or by divying up each equivalence class's measure amongst the individual elements in some way. If every measurable set has non-zero measure, then you can ensure that every element of $\mathbb N$ has non-zero value.

Comment: Yes, I can trivially define my $\sigma$-algebra to be lesser, but I particularly asked for measures that *could not& be extended.

Comment: Yes, missed that. Pretty easy to extend any such measure, so no, it is not possible.